# ASP.Net Chart controls Vs Highcharts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, highcharts

I want to develop a web dashboard in .NET. The backend will be Vb.NET. There are lot of chart controls in ASP.Net using which charts can be created. But as far as I know these charts wont be interactive. so I am thinking to use Highcharts. Please help me with your Suggestions. What is the best way to develop interactive dashboard in .NET?

Comment: What are the controls that you need to include in a _Dashboard_ ? what interaction(s) that you need to do with a chart ?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616156/Simple-Dashboard)?

Comment: you can use AM charts http://www.amcharts.com/

Comment: Basically my dashboard will have Multiple Bar charts, Line chart, Line with bar chart and Pie chart. Features like zoom in, zoom out, filter with legends are required.

Comment: Is it possible to create interactive charts using ASP.Net chart controls?

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts is a great product that is very easy to integrate in .NET.

For the page that needs a chart, you simply call a controller method that returns your data with Json and load that into the chart.

Here's a great tutorial:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820349/Highcharts-in-asp-net-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Is it possible to create interactive charts using ASP.Net Chart Controls?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, they haven't been updated in many years